# How to store attribute and value of a XML tag using XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<paths>
    <path action="M">some/path</path>
    <path action="D">another/path</path>
</paths>
```

I am trying to read it using the following classes:

```
public class Paths {
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="path")
    private ArrayList<Path> paths;  
}

@XStreamAlias("path")
public class Path {
    String path;
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String action;
}
```

The value of 'action' (Path.action) is really stored. But I only get NULL for the Path.path variable.

Any ideas of what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try ToAttributedValueConverter:

```
@XStreamAlias("path")
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"path"})
public class Path {
  String path;
  String action;
}
```